# Replacing a roman script MS Doc with unicode text : replaceText taking too long time

Tags: java, apache-poi, doc

I am trying to convert contents of a MS-DOC file from Roman to Unicode script. When the Roman file contains all roman letters, replacement works well, but when it contains few unicode or non roman words, the replacement takes too long time and program gets stuck at

```
document.getRange().replaceText("romanString","unicodeString");
```

What can be the reason?

Comment: If you take a thread dump when it gets stuck, what does the stacktrace show it blocking on?

Comment: @Gagravarr It seems it's stuck here (is it?)                        ' "main" prio=10 tid=0x00007f516800a000 nid=0x2129 runnable [0x00007f5171592000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
 at org.apache.poi.hwpf.sprm.CharacterSprmUncompressor.uncompressCHP(CharacterSprmUncompressor.java:87).. '

Comment: OK, that shouldn't be somewhere it should block. Have you made sure you're using the latest version of Apache POI?